# Android layout with dynamic content text

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a android layout with 5 textview elements. The layout should be like this:

```
DynamicLargeText1                                 DynamicLargeText2
DynamicSmallText1              DynamicSmallText2  DynamicSmallText3
```

Since all textview elements can have their content text grow/shrink (dynamic) I need specially
the two elements (DynamicSmallText2 and DynamicSmallText3) to be positioned correctly since there is a fixed space between those two elements. E.g when DynamicSmallText2 grows in context text id should not overlap DynamicSmallText3 and opposite.

I hope some can help me, thx in advance.

Smalltext2 and SmallText3 are overlapping in my code ?

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/largeText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="largeText1" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="smallText1"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeText1"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/largeText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="largeText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="largeText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeText2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="smallText3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/largeText2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/smallText2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use gridlayout for that !!

Comment: thanks! I will try with RelativeLayout first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **weight** concept like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

        <TextView
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Modified your code on Relative layout**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/smallText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/smallText2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/smallText2"
        android:text="smallText3" />
```

Comment: Updated answer check now

Comment: Nice - that worked! :) Do you see other improvements or issues ?

Comment: No that's fine no performance issues , You must accept this as an answer.

Comment: Ahem, whose idea again was it to use a relative layout? :p

Comment: It was actually mine. I really need to learn this layout since it can be usefull everywhere.

Comment: ...I provided the answer you used. No matter, so long as you got there.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, then add attributes in your TextView declarations of "android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" for example in textView2 which will keep textView2 below 1 at all times.

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicting layout parameters that cannot all be satisfied at the same time. To achieve the result you want, remove `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` from `smallText3`.